# How to echo multi lined strings in a Bourne shell

Tags: echo, sh, multiline

I want to create some scripts for filling some templates and inserting them into my project folder. I want to use a shell script for this, and the templates are very small so I want to embed them in the shell script. The problem is that `echo` seems to ignore the line breaks in my string. Either that, or the string doesn't contain line breaks to begin with. Here is an example:

```
MY_STRING="
Hello, world! This
Is
A
Multi lined
String."

echo -e $MY_STRING
```

This outputs:

```
Hello, world! This Is A Multi lined String.
```

I'm assuming `echo` is the culprit here. How can I get it to acknowledge the line breaks?

Comment: This is actually a Bourne shell question (not bash specific). Would you mind editing the title accordingly?

Comment: Jens: Be bold, you can make these edits yourself (like I just did).

Comment: @tripleee: Just wanted to be nice and not step on anyone's toe. I'll go for it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need double quotes around the variable interpolation.

```
 echo -e "$MY_STRING"
```

This is an all-too common error. You should get into the habit of always quoting strings, unless you specifically need to split into whitespace-separated tokens or have wildcards expanded.

So to be explicit, the shell will normalize whitespace when it parses your command line. You can see this if you write a simple C program which prints out its `argv` array.

```
argv[0]='Hello,'
argv[1]='world!'
argv[2]='This'
argv[3]='Is'
argv[4]='A'
argv[5]='Multi'
argv[6]='lined'
argv[7]='String.'
```

By contrast, with quoting, the whole string is in `argv[0]`, newlines and all.

For what it's worth, also consider here documents (with `cat`, not `echo`):

```
cat <<"HERE"
foo
Bar
HERE
```

You can also interpolate a variable in a here document.

```
cat <<HERE
$MY_STRING
HERE
```

... although in this particular case, it's hardly what you want.

Comment: Cool, but could you explain why before I mark your answer correct? EDIT: Oh right I get it now. I forgot that Bash doesn't pass strings like other script languages

Comment: Notice edits. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

`echo` is so nineties. [The new (POSIX) kid on the block is `printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html).

```
 printf '%s\n' "$MY_STRING"
```

No `-e` or SYSV vs BSD echo madness and full control over what gets printed where and how wide, escape sequences like in C. Everybody please start using `printf` now and never look back.

Comment: +1, printf has lots more handy formattings

Comment: I like how `printf` in bash holds true to the spirit of `printf` in the C language. It is surprisingly feature-rich and robust.

Comment: @Yokai Even better, it's *not* a bash thing. Any shell can use this utility (but shells may implement it as a builtin).

Answer (score 2):

Try this  :

```
echo  "$MY_STRING"
```