# Grep a specific string from bash script and compare

Tags: bash

i have a large log file A.log, i want to grep ONE CERTAIN STRING from the last 10 lines and compare to a variable (FTP_SUCCESS_MSG), how can i do that?

something like:

```
logs='/tmp/A.log'
FTP_SUCCESS_MSG="226 Transfer complete"
if [tail -10 $logs == $FTP_SUCCESS_MSG] ; 
then 
    echo "Success"  
else
    echo "Failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if tail -10 "$logs" | grep -Fq "$FTP_SUCCESS_MSG" ;  then ...
```

[Notice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586252/874188) how `[` is not present in the condition (and if it were, it would require non-optional spaces on both sides).

[Notice also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10583216/874188) how variable interpolations are in double quotes unless you require the shell to tokenize the value and perform wildcard expansion on the tokens.