# New line in git hook

Tags: git, sh, githooks

I have a git hook which calls a php file. The php file will produce an output (after running some Unit Tests). Te hook file is a sh file. The output from php file is echoed to the terminal, but \n is stripped, and everything is on a single line. Any ideas what I have to do to have new lines?

Thanks

Comment: if you are using print or echo statements in PHP, you need to actually put a \n in the statement itself.  Remember that \n won't be interpreted as a newline if you put it inside single quotes.  You must use double quotes to allow interpolation, e.g., `print("Hello, World!\n");`

Comment: Already did that. echo "Test\n" and echo "Test \r\n" just to be sure. Still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and, in your sh script,

- assign the output of the php script to a variable `avar`;
- echo that variable with:

  ```
  echo -e "${avar}"
  ```

That should keep the newlines, as mentioned in "[echo multiple lines into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10583216/6309)".

The same link mentions `printf` as well.

```
printf '%s\n' "${avar}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but echo -e is not supported for me. Nothing is printed. I ended up using printf instead.

Comment: @heXer Sure. The link I mentioned has printf as well. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `printf '%s\n' "$output"`

The key elements are `%s` which interprets the output as string, and the double quotes `""` which interpret the entire string as a single input. If you don't add the double quotes then every space is replaced by \n, so you would end up with a single word per line. Obviously, the actual string to display is stored in `$output`.

Reference:
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf

Comment: I just saw your answer. +1. Good description of the key element.